# CPU Usage relative to number of users? - ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, cpu-usage

My Asp.net application uses
25-30% of the CPU on a test server which has 600 MB Ram on it.

I can see the asp_wb process taking that much percentage of CPU.

This is when I am testing using one user.

How many users can the server afford then without falling over?

Is there a relationship between the CPU Usage and number of user aka if there are 2 users my application will sky rocket to 60% of memory usage?

Or does/Should/How does the server handle this?

Comment: One thing to consider with a web app is that your typical user doesn't stress the server continuously - they might request a page every 10 or 20 seconds, maybe a lot less.  If your ASP.NET app with one user is running at 25-30% CPU *consistently*, I'd guess it's doing a lot more than just serving page requests. What else is it doing?  Or, is this a single-user test run that's artificially running very quickly?

Comment: It only when a request is being made back to the db. it just to 25-30% for few seconds and then drops again as soon as it has data.

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net is base on pools and not on users.

Some memory per user is going on user session, but I believe that you not hold huge amount of data on sessions (did you ?).

Now I suggest ti run process explorer from sysinternals, and check on **w3wp.exe** the **working set** and the **virtual size** of the memory for this. You can do that by open this 2 columns on **Process Memory** tab.

Then you see there how many memory asp.net needs for your application.

**Second step if to check  how you have configure your pool** by open it. Maybe you have configure it to recycle too often, or to recycle when you have more than 125k working set memory, and your program have 200k working set memory. So you need to recalibrate some values.

Together with process explorer you can see how much memory your application need, and setup correctly the pool.

Of cource maybe there are other problems and other issues with the memory **but asp.net is not eat memory** for every user and **you need to check where your memory is used** - and the process explorer is a good tool for this job.

Hope this help.